# condition_variable not always working

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

It seems like `condition_variable` `notify_one` doesn't always work the way it should.

```
struct Task {
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic_bool launch{false};
};
void job(Task& task) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{task.mutex};
    task.cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return task.launch == true; });
}
int main() {
    for (auto i=0 ; i<1000*1000 ; i++) {
        Task task;
        std::thread thread{job, std::ref(task)};
        task.launch = true;
        task.cv.notify_one();
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

This program will almost never reach the end, it stops forever in the loop a vast majority of the time.
Why does that happen?

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen? These are fundamental parts of a good question...

Comment: Thank you @UlrichEckhardt , I expect the program to finish, and it almost never does.

Comment: And where exactly does it hang? Which line is the last that's successfully executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes here:

- If you sync access to an object, you don't need atomic types for that object. Your `atomic_bool` just causes overhead.
- If you want to sync access to the `launch` flag, you need to lock its mutex before writing to it. You don't do that in `main()`.

Explanation:

1. `main()` creates `task`
2. `main()` creates `thread`
3. `job()` locks the mutex
4. `job()` checks `launch`, which is false
5. `main()` sets `launch`
6. `main()` signals the CV, which nobody receives
7. `job()` waits for the CV due to the value of `launch` in step 4

Normally, steps 3 and 6 would be atomic because any other thread should not have touched `launch` without locking the mutex. Since that didn't happen, the interleaving of dependent operations was allowed to take place, which finally caused the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: So specifically, the *reason* that `job()` waits for the CV at step 6, is because the `main` function didn't synchronise the write to `launch` and so the thread can't necessarily see the change? If the thread saw `launch` as true, then it never would have blocked on the condition variable, because `condition_variable::wait` checks the predicate before waiting.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe my explanation was wrong, @SteveJessop. Also, yours doesn't improve it either, because the `atomic<bool>` should have made this safe. I'll add another explanation.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to work out. I now think the answer to my question is "no". The atomic type means that blocking on the CV is sequenced with respect to `main` writing to `launch`. But there's still nothing to sequence the thread blocking on the CV after `main` notifying the CV.

Comment: why nobody receives during step 6? 
Yes, `job()` checked during `4)` but it's still waiting inside this condition var

Comment: Waiting on a CV with a predicate callback (lambda) first checks the predicate (step 4). Then, it atomically unlocks the mutex and blocks on the CV (step 7). It is not blocked after step 4. This works, because the condition is protected by the mutex, unless someone (`main()` in this case) breaks the contract and accesses the data without holding the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want, but your problem is that is may happen that the main realizes `launch=true` and `notify_one()` before the thread had time to call `wait`. In this case, you should know that `notify` is not delayed, thus your main will be blocked on `join` while the thread is blocked on `wait`.